# Creating a calender in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 5 fields in a query.

Employee, Project ID, Year, Month, and Day

I need to put all the query data into a Report where the data is sorted by Year, Month, and Employee, and each Project ID needs to be placed under its appropriate date.

```
My Query:

Alice | P555 | 2014 | 11 November | 29
Darth | P999 | 2014 | 12 December | 27
Bob   | P555 | 2014 | 12 December | 28
Darth | P555 | 2014 | 12 December | 29
Alice | P999 | 2014 | 12 December | 29
Bob   | P999 | 2014 | 12 December | 29
Alice | P999 | 2014 | 12 December | 30
Alice | P555 | 2015 |  1 January  |  3
Alice | P999 | 2015 |  1 January  |  4
Darth | P555 | 2015 |  1 January  |  4
```

It needs to look something like this.

```
Calendar Report:

2014
   11 November   1 | 2 | ... | 28 |  29  | 30
         Alice     |   | ... |    | P555 | 

   12 December   1 | 2 | ... |  27  |  28  |  29  |  30  | 31
         Alice     |   | ... |      |      | P999 | P999 |   
         Bob       |   | ... |      | P555 | P999 |      | 
         Darth     |   | ... | P999 |      | P555 |      |   

2015
     1 January   1 | 2 |   3  |   4  | 5 | ... | 30
         Alice     |   | P555 | P999 |   | ... | 
         Darth     |   |      | P555 |   | ... |
```

I am able to create rows with the Year, Month, and Employee, but I do not know how to create the columns or how to add Project ID's once I do create them. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: All the days are in one row? i.e. not grouped by weeks like if you were in Outlook)

Comment: @Brad Correct, each month needs to be in its own, individual row unlike Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crosstab query should get you pretty close to what you want

```
TRANSFORM First(Calendar.[Project ID]) AS [FirstOfProject ID]
SELECT Calendar.Year, Calendar.Month, Calendar.Employee
FROM Calendar
GROUP BY Calendar.Year, Calendar.Month, Calendar.Employee
PIVOT Calendar.Day;
```

I do not quite see why you do not just use a datetime field rather than separating out year, month and day.

Comment: I could use a Crosstab Query, but then I would not be able to separate months/years into separate tables. I could also make a separate Crosstab for each month, but if more days were added to the table I would have to manually enter more month queries.

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not make sense to me in the light of the question you asked. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I need to do is take a bunch of data that is in a table/query and place it into a Report. Data can be added or removed from the table/query at any time. I need to make a calendar in  report that categorizes the data into year, then month, then employee. By categorizing the data I create a calendar. This calendar is NOT separated by weeks like it would be in Outlook. I can't use a Crosstab because I would not be able to group the data by year, then month, then employee.... I'm not sure if I cleared that up or made it more confusing >_<;

Comment: I do not see why a crosstab cannot be grouped by year, then month, then employee. My example illustrates such grouping. If you want a report, why are you not using report grouping? You can ensure that all days are included by using an IN statement.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. Yes the above does separate it as I need it to be :) I guess the reason I am set in it needing to be in reports, is because I need it to display the correct amount of days for all months. For example: January shows all 31 days, even if there is only one assignment for that month. February should have 28/29 days depending on leap year, etc, etc.

Comment: You can use `PIVOT Calendar.Day In (1,2,3,4 ... 30,31)`, otherwise you will have to build the query in VBA

Comment: BTW, you might also like to consider a calendar table, always very useful. ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx )